# Is it possible to "inherit" an implemented iterator?

Tags: java, iterator, extend

I am working on a java homework and right now, I have an implemented iterator in my ArrayIndexed list class that looks like this ( I have implemented them with functions written but for simplicity of post I truncated them):

```
public class ArrayIndexedList<T> implements IndexedList<T> {
//some other functions

@Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new ArrayIndexedListIterator();
  }

  private class ArrayIndexedListIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    private int nextIndex;

    private ArrayIndexedListIterator() {
      nextIndex = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() 
    @Override
    public T next()
```

Now I want to write a class ComplexIndexList that extends this class. My question is, is it possible to write an iterator that extends the one I wrote in ArrayIndexedList and override their functions, next and has next? Our teacher only taught us how to implement the Iterator class, so I am a little worried about doing so. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you allowed to move the `ArrayIndexedListIterator` out of the `ArrayIndexedList` class? If you can do that, then you can inherit `ArrayIndexedListIterator`.

Comment: I don't think I can. Is there a particular reason that prevents me from inheriting this iterator?

Comment: Yes, because it is `private`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I completely forgot about I set it as private. Is it a bad design to make iterator as public? I tried and I think I can inherit it if I set it as public.

Comment: Well, if you want to inherit it in a subclass, you should at least use the default protection level, so that subclasses in the same package can access (inherit) it.